# New Page does not found after create it in IE SharePoint 2013 Publishing Site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, publishing-page

I have created pages in IE, but it does not opens, it shows an error

**The page you're looking for doesn't exist**.

If I have created the new page with Chrome it's worked.

[image]

How to fix this issue?

Comment: is the page checked in / published ?

Comment: Yes, This page is published. :(
Still no clue!
But those are opens in the Chrome!